# couldtn't display data on textfield without tapping in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i am developing a payment processing iPhone application and also able to read information from card to my app using a card reader device but after reading card information i am unable to show those data to textfields of my view it displays only after tapping on textfields
please see if anyone can help me...

Comment: paste some relevant code

Comment: Is the text field in a table cell or in a view?

Answer (score 0):

the code should be something like this:

```
-(void)showCard{
nsstring *cardnumber = [[nsstring alloc]initwithformat:@"%@", cardData];
self.textField.text = cardnumber;}
```

thats how i do it and for me it automatically shows it
make sure that its not in an action where you tap the text field and that its in its own method

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the code to update the field is in the wrong place. If you have put the code in the delegate method

```
textFielDdidBeginEditing
```

the code would not be ran until the textField gains focus through an event such as a tap.
Try moving it into its own method that is called whenever the card reader has finished.